# Generate two columns from three different tables and calculate the ratio of those columns using a grouping variable

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-aurora

I am trying to get two counts of the occurence of an event with two different WHERE clauses. I would like the end result columns to be displayed side by side. Lastly, for each count, I need to obtain a display name column from another table. I would like to do all this in a query.

**EDIT**
Changed the grouping variable to table1.column1 (it's equivalent since it is the name rather than the id, but both should be unique.

```
SELECT table1.column1, COUNT(DISTINCT table2.column1) AS newcolumn1
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table1.column2 = table2.column2)
WHERE table2.column3 != 'var1'
GROUP BY table1.column1
UNION ALL
SELECT table1.column1, COUNT(DISTINCT table2.column1) AS newcolumn2
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table1.column2 = table2.column2)
WHERE table2.column3 = 'var2'
GROUP BY table1.column1
```

This sort of does what I want, but it stacks the columns instead of displaying them side by side. The end game is to have a column that is the ratio of newcolumn 1 and newcolumn 2. Unfortunately, this is a far as I managed to get.

Comment: selecting column1 but grouping by column2 is very suspect and may fail if only_full_group_by is set. And since I can't guess intent from this dubious code please add sample data and expected outcome as text. Also search for conditional aggregation.

Comment: I could group by table1.column1 as well. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using separated left join instead of union

```
    select table1.column1, tvar1.newcolumn1, tvar2.newcolumn2 
    from table1 
    left join (
        SELECT table1.column1, COUNT(DISTINCT table2.column1) AS newcolumn1
        FROM table2
        LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table1.column2 = table2.column2)
        WHERE table2.column3 = 'var1'
        GROUP BY table1.column1
    ) tvar1 on tvar1.column1 = table1.column1
    left join  (

        SELECT table1.column1, COUNT(DISTINCT table2.column1) AS newcolumn2
        FROM table2
        LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table1.column2 = table2.column2)
        WHERE table2.column3 = 'var2'
        GROUP BY table1.column1
    ) tvar2 on tvar2.column1 = table1.column1
```

Comment: I tried to adapt this but my sql console seems to think there's an error in the syntax. I can't seem to figure out where

Comment: answer updated   ..  missing on clause in first left join